# Rebinning data in Excel

Tags: excel, binning

I have some wind data in excel that is binned by wind speed and direction.  I want to re-bin it to cover different intervals (assuming the data is uniform across the original intervals). i.e I want to go from:
[image]

To

[image]

Can anyone give me some pointers?  Struggling to think of an elegant way to do this.

Comment: Are the units the same way round in your current bins? Also what happens to a value of say 22.5. Which bin does it sit in in your second format?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "units same way round".  The units are the same throughout (i.e. m/s and degrees and the bins are a count).  Good point about the intervals.  They'll need to be defined as [lower value, upper value).

Comment: I understand that. Just trying to understand the reasoning behind your new bins

Comment: The new bin could in theory be anything.  But generally its about reducing the number of bins to fewer representative cases (to feed into simulation work)

Comment: And I'm guessing you don't still have the raw data to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately not